# Posting JSON data to java web services from iOS

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I am trying to send simple text or name as json to my java web service from iOS app but unfortunately no luck. Here is my iOS POST code as follows:

```
- (IBAction)cmdRegister:(id)sender {    
    AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [operationManager setSecurityPolicy:policy];
    operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operationManager POST:@"http://localhost:8080/com.webservice/rest/status/member/"
                parameters:@{@"name":@"john"}
                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                       NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
                   }
                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
                   }
     ];     
}
```

Here is my java web service method:

```
@POST
@Path("/member/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addNewCustomer(@PathParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
  String returnString=null;
  MemberDAO dao = new MemberDAO();
  try{
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
      Customer customer =mapper.readValue(name, Customer.class);

      //add to database the passed in params
      int returnCode =dao.insertMembers(name);

      //return the success or failure
      if(returnCode ==200){
        returnString ="Member has been added";
      } else {
        return Response.status(500).entity("Unable to process member    registration").build();
      }

  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return Response.ok(returnString).build();
}
```

running this as is no error and no database update. I have searched and found similar posts but no clue please help.

I am not sure if what i am doing wrong.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: So you're saying you get a return code 200 from the server, but the database isn't updated?  Have you dumped the transmitted data on either end to see if it's correct??

Answer (score 0):

I can help you in the part iOS. But I don't know if you code java server(I think use JBoss) is correct.

You show me code and try this code(iOS):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *strURL = @"http://YOUR_IP:YOUR_PORT/YOUR_PATH/../../..";

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager     = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializerRequest = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [serializerRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializerResponse = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    serializerResponse.readingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
    serializerResponse.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

    manager.requestSerializer = serializerRequest;
    manager.responseSerializer = serializerResponse;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SIMPLE_IMAGE.png"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"name":@"Jhon"};
    [manager POST:strURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"photo"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        strResultResponse = operation.responseString;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        strResultResponse = operation.responseString;
    }];
}
```

This code you send to server, parameters string and nsdata(image). You adapte in your code and try run.
I'm sorry, if it was not much help. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @Ryuchan i will have a go and let you know the outcome. The web service was based on glass fish 4.0 and I am not sure if need to configure glass fish to accept POST. I can easily use GET to pass params and return JSON with out issue. Please also let me know if you know anything about how to configure web server to accept POST from client.

Answer (score 0):

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationmanager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializerRequest = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[serializerRequest setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 operationmanager.requestSerializer = serializerRequest;

operationmanager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", nil];

[operationmanager POST:getCategoryPath parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```